How do I call a custom serializer from a _node_update hook?
We inherited a legacy Drupal project that has an entity called Products. We expose an API endpoint that returns all Products as JSON.
Our project uses a module that contains a custom serializer:
// modules\custom\my_module\src\Plugin\views\style\CustomizedSerializer.php

class CustomizedSerializer extends Serializer {
  function render($unserialized) {
    \Drupal::logger('php')->notice('CustomizedSerializer::render');
    // ...
  }
}

We know this custom serializer is used for Products because after viewing the JSON API endpoint for Products the above log statement in render shows up in our logs.
When a Product is edited through the admin portal, we want to dump all the Products' data into a static JSON file, using the CustomizedSerializer to generate the JSON. Here's our attempt:
// modules\custom\my_module\my_module.module

function my_module_node_update($node) {
  if ($node->getType() == 'product') {
    $nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type', 'product')->execute();
    $nodes = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);
    $serializer = \Drupal::service('serializer');
    $result = $serializer->serialize($nodes, 'json');
    $file = fopen('sites/default/files/products.json', 'w');
    fwrite($file, $result);
    fclose($file);
  }
}

However, \Drupal::service('serializer') appears to call a serializer other than the CustomizedSerializer since the above log statement doesn't appear, and the output is different from the output of the JSON API endpoint.
How can we call the CustomizedSerializer?

There should be code comments for the CustomizedSerializer class. Can you please post those?
